# How to reuse animation tag in SVG without javascript

Tags: animation, svg

I want to reuse `<animate>` tags without javascript. Something like this:

```xml
<svg>
    <defs>
        <animate id="shrink"
            attributeName="width"
            from="100%" to="0%"
            dur="5s"
            repeatCount="1"
            fill="freeze" />
    </defs>

    <rect width="100%" 
        height="10%"
        fill="blue"
        animate="#shrink"/>
</svg>
```

But all the examples I find have the animation inside the `<rect>` tag or they use javascript etc.

Since you can reuse graphics gradients and masks, is there a way to reuse an `<animate>` tag?

Comment: the tag is called `<animate>` and not `<animation>`. Also, you should call the def with the tag `<use>`, the attribute `animate` is invalid. Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLJfY/ However, I could not make the animation work, sorry about that. Animation elements are authorized inside defs though, cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs

Comment: [fixed animation -> animate] thanks for looking into it. I tried the <use> before. I tried using it in an <animate>, too. I combed the developer.mozilla.org references, saw that <animate> is valid for <defs> which is a big clue that is should be doable.

Answer (score 8):

You're close but linking actually works the other way round. The object being animated needs the id and the animate then points to it i.e.

```xml
<svg>
    <defs>
        <animate xlink:href="#r"
            attributeName="width"
            from="100%" to="0%"
            dur="5s"
            repeatCount="1"
            fill="freeze" />
    </defs>
    <rect id="r"
        width="100%"
        height="10%"
        fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

It's not possible to "reuse" SMIL animation elements.

Comment: That's cool, I wasn't aware of that.  Thanks for teaching us!

Comment: Alright, but is it not possible to use the same animation over and over? A fade out, a shrink something you'll use on multiple elements without having to retype the <animation>?

Comment: No, that's one of the basic limitations of SMIL. One of the objectives of the in-progress SVG 2 animation specification is addressing that shortcoming.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on Robert's answer, you can reuse elements that contain animations with `<use>`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <rect id="animation" width="10" height="10" 
          fill="#ff0000" opacity="0.25">
      <animate attributeName="opacity" 
               from="0.25" to="1" 
               begin="0s" dur="1s"/>
    </rect>
  </defs>

  <!-- use  multiple times -->
  <use xlink:href="#animation"/>
  <use xlink:href="#animation" x="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: One warning: if you are going to re-use an element that has an animation, make sure you follow this way of declaring the animation (as a child of the graphic element) rather than using the `xlink:href` method.  The second version *should* work, but doesn't in Firefox because of the way they implement `<use>` elements.